# Reactjs Button component not updating state on pressup

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component

****UPDATED***

My state is not being updated for any of the buttons.
How do i pass the value pressed on button.js as condition on handleChange?

1. want to update the state value using a callack when button component is clicked
2. display results in another component
3. When i press button, my state is not updating

**App.js**

```
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0);
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0);
  // const [all, setAll] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (value) => {
    // const data = ["good", "bad", "neutral"];
    if (value === "good") {
      setGood(good + 1);
      console.log(value);
    } else if (value === "neutral") {
      setNeutral(neutral + 1);
    } else if (value === "bad") {
      setBad(bad + 1);
    }
  };
Return (
    <Container className="Container">
      <h2>Give Feedback</h2>
      <Button onClick={handleChange} />
      {/* statictics  */}
      <Statistics />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

**Button.js**

```
export default function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button value="good" onChange={props.handleChange}>
        Good
      </button>
      <button value="neutral" onClick={props.handleChange}>
        Neutral
      </button>
      <button value="bad" onClick={props.handleChange}>
        Bad
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

new error received, advising me to add a lifecycle method.
i dont know if this is overkill and if there's an easier way of implementing this count solution.

[error received after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJcFW.png)

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, there are several problems with your code:

- In your `button` component, you are looking for `props.handleChange`; but in your `App` component, you are passing in `onClick`; you should either do `<Button handleChange={handleChange} />` or in your `Button` component do `onClick={props.onClick}` (I personally prefer the latter)
- React needs you to name your components with first capital letters, so `button` -> `Button`
- in your `handleChange` function, you are expecting `value` to come in, but you are gonna receive click event, and you should extract value out of it

Answer (score 0):

In Button compoennt the props is handleChange, so you need to do like below

Changes in App.js for your case:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0);
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0);
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = value => {
    // const data = ["good", "bad", "neutral"];
    if (value === "good") {
      setGood(good);
      console.log(value);
    } else if (value === "neutral") {
      setNeutral(neutral);
      console.log(value);
    } else if (value === "bad") {
      setBad(bad);
      console.log(value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Give Feedback</h2>
      <Button handleChange={handleChange} />
      {/* statictics  */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Changes in button component for your updated case

```
 import React from "react";
// import { Button, Table, Container } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function Button(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button value="good" onClick={() => props.handleChange("good")}>
        Good
      </button>
      <button value="neutral" onClick={() => props.handleChange("neutral")}>
        Neutral
      </button>
      <button value="bad" onClick={() => props.handleChange("bad")}>
        Bad
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Madking Did it help you?

Comment: need help with this 
"in your handleChange function, you are expecting value to come in, but you are gonna receive click event, and you should extract value out of it"

Comment: Your click is handled by the Button component in which you have made 3 buttons. onClick is initiated from that component and than it call its parent through callback. And since in your Button component you are doing `onClick={props.handleChange}` , so that makes it necessary to have handleChange prop present in parent component. Hence I suggested for the change I have mentioned in my answer

Comment: I have edited my answer and suggested the way by which you can pass the values of good, neutral or bad. You can once try that.

Comment: @Madking Please accept the answer by clicking on tick besides the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)

Comment: sowi for delay, thanks for the assistance really aprpeciate it.
I discovered another error relating to below.
After searching i found out that calling setstate method witin my handlechage method was causing this errror and i need to add lifecycle method componentDidUpdate. dont know if this is required for such a small application.





```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.```

Comment: For this case I need to see your whole component as it looks like that you are somewhere doing setState indefinitely. You can place your working code snippet on codeSandbox

Comment: here we go https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-leakey-t48tp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can directly copy paste the code for App.js and your button component. I have solved the errors and now it goes properly to the callbacks. You can accept the answer by clicking green tick besides my answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I cant see your edit @RaghvenderKataria  on my sandbox, im still getting the error.
https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-leakey-t48tp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark